# Bash script for execute one command for many files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, video-conversion, transcode

I just tried to clear my holiday video stuff and found program for stibilizng vision. 
There are a lot of files so I made script to stabilize all. Firstly I need to run command:

```
transcode -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i DSCNXXX.MOV
```

I wrote a script for that but it is not working because stabilizing finishes after first file. I mean first file is done then it do not pass to second. The script looks like:

```
for file in /media/Przenośny/transcdoe/*
do
transcode -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i "$file" >> results.out
done
```

Its worth to add, when I cancel operation with ctrl+c script automaticly moves to next clip and so on.

Comment: What is in `results.out` after the script finishes?

Comment: results.out is empty becaouse script can't finish first file it never stops on itself, I froce stop with ctrl+z

Comment: transcdoe or transcode?

Comment: its the path on my computer all paths are right

Comment: He meant you have a typo, your script shows `/media/Przenośny/transcdoe/*` and presumably you meant `/media/Przenośny/transcode/*`. Anyway, what happens if you run the command manually for one file? Does it ever finish? I mean if you run `transcode -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i "DSCNXXX.MOV" >> results.out`

Comment: @terdon your solution is right, just first file in folder got problems with the command and even if I enter it manually it does not finish, all other clips are doing just fine with the script I posted above. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the find command:

```
find /media/Przenośny/transcode/* -exec transcode -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i {} \;
```

I have to wait ~1min after this message to see the next file to be transcoded:

```
[decoder.c] cancelling the import threads 0:01:24,  ( 4, 9| 0, 0| 6, 1)
```

Redirecting with `>>` is useless as all the logs go to stderr and are pretty verbose (1 by frame)

Comment: thanks, but It was problem with first file script tried to stabilize, When I cancel first file rest are just fine. Thanks for answer :)